# FadeOut pseudo element transition not working?

Tags: javascript, css

I am always able to add fadeIn with a transition. But for some reason, fadeOut never works. Even after setting the opacity to 0 and transition on the parent body/class element.

I am wondering if it is possible to fade out the same like fade in works on click?

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and if it is possible to do this?

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: $text-body;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;

    &:after {
        content: '';
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -10;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1.2s ease-out;
    }

    &.bg-dark {
        &:after {
            background: rgba($color-black, 0.7);
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
            z-index: 100;
            transition: opacity 1.2s ease-out;
        }
    }

    @if $use-custom-fonts == true {
        font-family: $font-body-custom;
    } @else {
        font-family: $font-body;
    }
}
```

My JS:

```
(() => {
    const menuToggle = document.querySelector('[rel="js-menu"]');
    const body = document.body;

    if (!menuToggle) {
        return;
    }

    const sideNav = document.querySelector('[rel="js-side__nav"]');
    const sideNavClose = document.querySelector('[rel="js-side__close"]');

    const openMenu = (e) => {
        sideNav.classList.add('side__nav--open');
        body.classList.add('bg-dark');

        e.preventDefault();
    };

    const closeMenu = (e) => {
        if (sideNav.classList.contains('side__nav--open')) {
            sideNav.classList.remove('side__nav--open');
            body.classList.remove('bg-dark');
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    };

    document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
        if (e.keyCode === 27) {
            if (sideNav.classList.contains('side__nav--open')) {
                sideNav.classList.remove('side__nav--open');
                body.classList.remove('bg-dark');
            }
        }
    });

    menuToggle.addEventListener('click', openMenu);
    sideNavClose.addEventListener('click', closeMenu);
})();
```

Comment: Where is your HTML? Please post a working snippet.

Comment: A snippet is *not* a link to your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `visibility: hidden;`. It hides your element instantly without transition which has effect only for `opacity`.

Another problem is that `background-color` is set only on `.bg-dark` and `transition` is set only for `opacity`. So opacity works but change of background color is instant.

I've provided example with removed `visibility` and applied `background` for initial state (without `.bg-dark`)

```js
(() => {
    const menuToggle = document.querySelector('[rel="js-menu"]');
    const body = document.body;

    if (!menuToggle) {
        return;
    }

    const sideNav = document.querySelector('[rel="js-side__nav"]');
    const sideNavClose = document.querySelector('[rel="js-side__close"]');

    const openMenu = (e) => {
        sideNav.classList.add('side__nav--open');
        body.classList.add('bg-dark');
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    const closeMenu = (e) => {
        if (sideNav.classList.contains('side__nav--open')) {
            sideNav.classList.remove('side__nav--open');
            body.classList.remove('bg-dark');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    
    menuToggle.addEventListener('click', openMenu);
    sideNavClose.addEventListener('click', closeMenu);
})();
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
body:after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  /* moved background style here */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  /* removed visibility */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1.2s ease-out;
}
body.bg-dark:after {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div rel="js-side__nav"></div>
<button rel="js-side__close">close</button>
<button rel="js-menu">open</button>
```

Comment: Removed visibility but still on close not fading out.

Comment: There is also problem with your `background-color`. Provided example.